# File 'src/app/app.component.spec.ts' is not part of Typescript project while upgrading to Angular 5

Tags: angular5

File 'src/app/app.component.spec.ts' is not part of Typescript project 'src/tsconfig.app.json' while upgrading to Angular 5

We have followed all the instructions for converting our project from angular 4 but are pulling out our hair over this one - anyone have any ideas?

We are getting this error from tslint...

Comment: the steps which you followed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the "lint" section of .angular-cli.json by replacing all of the "files" entries with "exclude" entries...

```
"lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "files": "src/**/*.ts"
},
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
  "files": "src/**/*.spec.ts"
},
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
  "files": "e2e/**/*.ts"
}]
```

becomes

```
"lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the files specified in our .angular-cli.json for our lint configuration, but we should have been just relying on the files specified in our tsconfig.json files. We removed the files from angular-cli.json and all is well.