# Warning Upgrade the Angular 7 to 9 get warning

Tags: angular, angular9

Update the Angular version in My project after when npm start give warning

[WARNING in E:\bansi\project\BTT\BTT_new - angular 9.0.1\BTTReport_AspnetZero_New\BTTCorpAngular-master\src\app\btt-report\monthly-report\monthly-report.component.spec.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsehz.png)
and when build my project get lots of error.I'm tired to change dependancy add and remove.

I'm added the tsconfig.app.json file

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
  "src/main.ts",
  "src/polyfills.ts"
],
 "include": [
 "src/**/*.ts"
],
   "exclude": [
   "src/test.ts",
   "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

[image: Ivy Workspace: <error>]

Comment: The warning is due to lint config. below discussion may help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778839/file-src-app-app-component-spec-ts-is-not-part-of-typescript-project-while-upg .

Comment: @LaminooLawrance It already added it not working.

Comment: @Bansi29 can u remove src? and try again? ==    "**/*.spec.ts", like this

Comment: Hi,@Energy  Thanks for the response but , it getting warnings as per `report\monthly-report.component.spec.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused. Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.`

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned here : [How to get rid of the warning .ts file is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729518/how-to-get-rid-of-the-warning-ts-file-is-part-of-the-typescript-compilation-but)

Removing `"src/**/*.ts"` from the include array does the trick.

Or you can just add the unused files in the exclude array on `tsconfig.app.json`