# New File are not using the project configuarion

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently update to `angular 10`, and now use `"typescript": "3.9.7"`

My project is working fine but today I tried to add a new folder in the project.

This new folder (that share a same parent with other working folder in the app) Is not considered to be inside my typescript project.

When I execute `Typescript : Go to project Configuration` it says that

> File is not part of a Typescript project

when I click to `Configure tsconfig.json` (which is already defined in my project) I get moved to my file that looks like this :

tsconfig.json (root folder)

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig that is following the Solution Style => https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-9/#solution-style-tsconfig

If I do `Typescript : Go to project Configuration` from any other file in the app they move me to
`/tsconfig.app.json` correctly.

Why are those new file not finding the correct configuration ?

How can I fix this issue ?

I am also already using the workspace typescript version
[image]

EDIT :

tsconfig.app.ts (root folder)

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json (root folder)

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

tsconfig.base.json(root folder)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@e2e/*": ["e2e/src/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

EDIT : related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18040

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778839/file-src-app-app-component-spec-ts-is-not-part-of-typescript-project-while-upg

Comment: thanks for the reply, my angular.json lint section already looks like something like what is provided in the post. angular-cli as been removed in angular 6

Comment: Can you share the content of your `./tsconfig.spec.json` and `./tsconfig.app.json`

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLUthanks for your time, I added them all.

Comment: can you try to add `"moduleResolution": "node",` above `"baseUrl": "./"` line in your `tsconfig.base.json` file?

Comment: If the above method doesn't work, please add a screenshot of your product file structure

Comment: the above method did not work.

here is the full tree 
https://i.imgur.com/OmJeFDN.png

(the new file is the one selected and do not work, the others (that were present before update works)